# ImportError Running Test.py

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, acrcloud

I recently downloaded ACRCloud and began trying to use it to recognize music on the Raspberry Pi. So, the first thing I did was run the setup.py script with the following command:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

Everything runs fine and all the necessary files are created. Next thing I did was enter my API information into the test.py file. It currently looks like this with the information entered:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

'''
    >>> python test.py test.mp3
'''

import os, sys
from acrcloud.recognizer import ACRCloudRecognizer
from acrcloud.recognizer import ACRCloudRecognizeType

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = {
        'host':'--------------',
        'access_key':'--------------',
        'access_secret':'--------------',
        'recognize_type': ACRCloudRecognizeType.ACR_OPT_REC_AUDIO, # you can replace it with [ACR_OPT_REC_AUDIO,ACR_OPT_REC_HUMMING,ACR_OPT_REC_BOTH], The SDK decide which type fingerprint to create accordings to "recognize_type".
        'debug':False,
        'timeout':10 # seconds
    }

    '''This module can recognize ACRCloud by most of audio/video file. 
        Audio: mp3, wav, m4a, flac, aac, amr, ape, ogg ...
        Video: mp4, mkv, wmv, flv, ts, avi ...'''
    re = ACRCloudRecognizer(config)

    #recognize by file path, and skip 0 seconds from from the beginning of sys.argv[1].
    print re.recognize_by_file(sys.argv[1], 0, 10)

    buf = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb').read()
    #recognize by file_audio_buffer that read from file path, and skip 0 seconds from from the beginning of sys.argv[1].
    print re.recognize_by_filebuffer(buf, 0, 10
```

Nothing other than the host, access key, or access secret have been touched, and I removed them here. Next, I try running the following command:

```
sudo python test.py test.mp3
```

This should return the song, as my directory contains both files. ls -la returns the following:

```
drwxrwxrwx 6 pi   pi       4096 Mar  9 15:26 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 pi   pi       4096 Feb 15 08:36 ..
drwxrwxrwx 2 pi   pi       4096 Mar  9 01:08 acrcloud
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root     4096 Mar  9 00:46 build
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Mar  9 00:46 dist
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Mar  9 00:46 pyacrcloud.egg-info
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi   pi        570 Feb 15 08:36 setup.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi   pi   10724969 Mar  9 01:07 test.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi   pi       1291 Mar  9 01:05 test.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi   pi      12288 Mar  9 00:54 .test.py.swp
```

However, when I run the command above, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    from acrcloud.recognizer import ACRCloudRecognizer
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/ACRCloud/raspberrypi/python2.7/acrcloud/recognizer.py", line 21, in <module>
    import acrcloud_extr_tool
ImportError: /home/pi/Downloads/ACRCloud/raspberrypi/python2.7/acrcloud/acrcloud_extr_tool.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have checked to ensure that the shared object file is where it says it is. Doing ls -la in the python2.7/acrcloud directory gives me the following:

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 pi   pi       4096 Mar  9 01:08 .
drwxrwxrwx 6 pi   pi       4096 Mar  9 15:26 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi   pi   11270324 Feb 15 08:36 acrcloud_extr_tool.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi   pi        182 Feb 15 08:36 __init__.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      157 Mar  9 01:08 __init__.pyc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi   pi      10990 Feb 15 08:36 recognizer.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     8693 Mar  9 01:08 recognizer.pyc
```

So it's pretty clear that I have everything there, and it's not a privilege issue. Not entirely sure what I should do.

Apologies for the lengthy post, just wanted to be completely thorough.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What's the system of Raspberry Pi you are using?